# ImportError : No module named RPi in <script> at line number 1

Tags: netbeans-platform

I am trying to execute a python code from java using jython.

Whenever I call the python code to be executed, I get an import error stating

> No module named RPi in  at line number 1

I have installed RPi module.

[image: code]

[image: code]

Comment: Please actually put the code into the question - I embedded the images but I will also vote to close because the code is not *in the question*.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the answer for this. I was using eval to run my Python program from java, when I changed the code to runtime.exec it actually worked by importing all required modules and libraries.